# Plotting Matlab graph in Excel?

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph, plot

I have created a graph in Matlab and was wondering how to transfer all X and Y points to Excel so I can recreate the plot?

This is most of my code, i'm just plotting Cp against TSR? But I was hoping to also have my output graph in Excel in order to compare it with other results.

```
% Variables
Q=1;
jj=1;                                           % Counter
tolerance=0.01;                                  % Tolerance Value
axial_induction=[0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0];
Check=1;                                        % Initial check value
axial_induction_old=[0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0];        % Initial value for old axial induction factor
relative_wind=[1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1]; 

Cl=[1.3; 1.1; 1; 0.9; 0.86; 0.83; 0.8; 0.75; 0.5];                                          % Lift Coefficients
Cd=[0.027; 0.024; 0.02; 0.019; 0.018; 0.016; 0.013; 0.012; 0.01];                           % Drag Coefficients

r_local=R/9*(1:9)';
r_over_R=r_local / R;

ii=0;                                                   % Counting Interval for integral values


for TSR=0.1:0.1:10                                      % TSR from 1 to 10
    disp(TSR)                                                                    
    Check=1;
ii=ii+1;


TSR_local=r_over_R .* TSR;    
relative_wind=(2/3)*atan(1./TSR_local);
C=((8*pi.*r_local) ./ (B.*Cl_design)).*(1-cos(relative_wind));
sigma=(B*C) ./ (pi.*R.*2);
sigma_local=(B*C) ./ (pi.*r_local.*2); 


axial_induction= 1 ./ (((4.*(sin(relative_wind).^2)) ./ (sigma_local.*Cl_design.*cos(relative_wind)))+1);
angular_induction= (1-(3.*axial_induction)) ./ ((4.*axial_induction)-1);
angular_velocity=22;


TSR_local = TSR .* (r_local./R);                                                                 % Local Tip Speed Ratio
relative_wind = (2/3) .* atan(1./TSR_local);                                                               % Angle of Relative Fluid



   while abs(Check)>=tolerance


axial_induction_old = axial_induction;        

relative_wind = atan(U.*(1-axial_induction))./((angular_velocity*R).*(1+angular_induction));

F=zeros(size(relative_wind));
for Q=1:length(relative_wind)
    if relative_wind(Q)<0;
    F(Q)=1;
    else
    F(Q)=(2/pi) .* acos(exp(-(((B/2) .* (1-(r_over_R(Q)))) ./ ((r_over_R(Q)) .* sin(relative_wind(Q))))));      % Tip Loss Factor
    end;
end;

alpha=relative_wind-S;


if axial_induction<0.4;
C_T=(sigma_local .* ((1-axial_induction).^2) .* ((Cl.*cos(relative_wind))+(Cd.*sin(relative_wind)))) ./ ((sin(relative_wind)).^2); 
else
    C_T=(8/9)+(4.*F-(40/9)).*axial_induction+((50/9)-4.*F).*axial_induction.^2;
end


for jj=1:length(C_T)
  angular_induction(jj) = 1 ./ ((4.*F(jj).*cos(relative_wind(jj))./(sigma_local(jj).*Cl(jj)))-1);

   if  C_T(jj) < 0.96;
      axial_induction(jj) = 1 / 1+(4*F(jj)*(sin(relative_wind(jj))^2)/(sigma_local(jj)*Cl(jj)*cos(relative_wind(jj))));
   else
       axial_induction(jj) = (1/F(jj)) .* abs(0.142+(0.0203-0.6427.*(0.889-C_T(jj))).^0.5);
   end;
end;




D=abs((8./(TSR.*8)).*(F.*(sin(relative_wind).^2).*(cos(relative_wind)-((TSR_local).*(sin(relative_wind)))).*(sin(relative_wind)+((TSR_local).*(cos(relative_wind)))).*(1-(Cd./Cl).*cot(relative_wind)).*(TSR_local.^2)));
Cp=sum(D(1:8));


Diff=axial_induction-axial_induction_old;
Check=max(Diff(:));
Check

   end

store_C(:,ii)=C;
store_sigma_local(:,ii)=sigma_local;
store_sigma(:,ii)=sigma;
store_Phi(:,ii)=relative_wind;
store_TSR_local(:,ii)=TSR_local;
store_axial_induction(:,ii)=axial_induction;
store_angular_induction(:,ii)=angular_induction;
store_axial_induction_old(:,ii)=axial_induction_old;
store_relative_wind(:,ii)=relative_wind;
store_Check(:,ii)=Check;
store_Diff(:,ii)=Diff;
store_Cp(:,ii)=Cp;
store_TSR(:,ii)=TSR;
store_F(:,ii)=F;

end


figure(1)
plot(store_TSR,store_Cp)
axis([0 8 0 0.6])

title('Cp vs Tip Speed Ratio')
xlabel('TSR')
ylabel('Cp')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am a bit of a Matlab novice, my graph contains a vast amount of x and y points and when plotted each value overwrites the previous one. I'm not sure how to just copy and paste it?

Comment: @Kevin Where does the data come from? Please include some code and then we can explain it to you

Comment: I added my code there, I dont expect u guys to read it all. Im just not sure how to use the xlswrite command or how i could copy and paste results from Matlab?

Comment: @Kevin sounds like all your data are in `store_TSR` and `store_Cp`, so in the matlab variable explorer you can literally double click on those variables and it will open them in a spreadsheet like interface that you can copy and paste from. Otherwise `xlswrite` is very easy and well documented, give it a try, I think you'll manage.